# Spring Boot Way to Replace Views in SQL

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**Context**

I've inherited a small Spring-based project --it tracks servers, software installations, etc for or teams internal use. It uses Angular front end and Spring/java/mysql back end for a restful back end.

I've converted it to Spring boot over the last few months.  I'm new to Spring and Spring boot. So I'm learning as I go along.

I started replacing the 'hand coded' sql with JPA ("spring-data-rest"). JPA has been easy for some tables, but not for others. For these "others":  *The hand-coded SQL uses "views" when retrieving data .*

**Approach**

Specifically, it uses this approach:

- When it creates or updates a table (e.g. "sites" table, as in "web site"), it  passes in the "ID's:" Server_id, product_id, customer_id etc.
- The software retrieves from a "sites view" that joins on the server , product, and customer tables, so that the java can retrieve server name, product name, customer name, etc. without a separate database call.

**Questions**

- What is the cleanest, most-Spring-boot-ish way to convert these "read-only views" to JPA?
- What generally is the cleanest way to handle 'star joins' in  Spring/JPA? (where one central table joins with several other tables to give the user the data he/she needs)

thanks

Comment: If the answer was helpful don't forget to accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you can use the usual [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) with [native query](https://github.com/roberthunt/spring-data-native-query-projection/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/co/rbrt/PersonRepository.java) to get data from views. Something like this:

```java
public interface ViewResult {
    String getField1();
    Integer getField2();
    Double getField3();
    //...
}

public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select v.field1 as field1, v.field2 as field2, v.field3 as field3 from some_view v", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ViewResult> getViewResult();
}
```

To work with complex query you can also use projections:

```java
@Query("select a as abc, b as bcd, c as cde from Abc a join a.bcd b join a.cde c")
List<AbcBcdCde> getComplexData();
```

where `AbcBcdCde` is a projection:

```java
public interface AbcBcdCde {
    Abc getAbc();
    Bcd getBcd();
    Cde getCde();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. As far as "spring-bootiness" goes, when dealing with joins and "bringing in extra data" to supplement the table columns, how do "projections" stack up with JPA "ManyToOne" relationships?

Comment: @user331465 In the query below the `a.bcd b` is a "ManyToOne" joined entity, for example, that can be getted with `getBcd()` getter in the projection (if I correct understood you..).

Comment: pardonne moi )) "In the query **above**..."